# Angular How to dynamically change a value from an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, ionic4

I have some code that I am working on, that allows a user to pick a contact, I want the code to be able to populate an array,

as that then populates the Html template with NgFor

However, I am battling to make the function change data in the array dynamically
could anyone help me or at least point me into a direction.

here is the relevant code
html file

```
<ion-list>

  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-item-group (click) = "pickContact()"  *ngFor="let contacts of mContacts">
          <ion-card>
              <ion-item lines = "none">             
                  <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">Name: {{contacts.name}}</ion-label>        
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item lines = "none" >
                  <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">Number: {{contacts.number}}</ion-label>
                </ion-item>       
          </ion-card>            
        </ion-item-group>    

      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

  </ion-grid>
</ion-list>
```

I want the function pickContact to be called when the card is selected and then populate the corrosponding element in the array.
ts file

```
export class ContactComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private contacts: Contacts) { }


  mContacts = [
   {
    name: [''],
    number: ['']
   },
   {
    name : ['Carl'],
    number: ['065 623 4567']
   }
  ];

  ngOnInit() {}

//currently thows an error:  
//Property 'name' does not exist on type '{ name: string[]; number: string[]; }[]'.

//Property 'number' does not exist on type '{ name: string[]; number: string[]; }[]'

  pickContact() {
    this.contacts.pickContact().then((contact) => {
    this.mContacts.name = contact.name.givenName;
    this.mContacts.number = contact.phoneNumbers[0].value;
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update you data like that, it is easier..

```
mContacts = [
  {
    name: '',
    number: '',
  },
  ...
];
```

You need to put your pickContact function inside ion-card with an the contact object to know exactly which contact you wanna pick.

let contacts --> let contact (it is one contact)

```
<ion-item-group *ngFor="let contact of mContacts">
   <ion-card (click)="pickContact(contact)">
      <ion-item lines = "none">             
         <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">Name: {{contact.name}}</ion-label>        
         </ion-item>
         <ion-item lines = "none" >
            <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">Number: {{contact.number}}
         </ion-label>
      </ion-item>       
   </ion-card>            
</ion-item-group>
```

Then in you component

```
...
pickContact(contact) {
   this.contacts.pickContact().then((contacts) => {
     contacts.forEach(c => {
        if (c.name === contact.name ) {
           // Do the matching
           const contactToUpdate = mContacts.find(c => c.name === contact.name)
           contactToUpdate.name = c.name;
           contactToUpdate.number = c.number;
        }
     })
});
```

}

I dont see exactly the use case here but this is something you can do.. There are of course better way to do it but I prefer keeping it simple.

One thing about this

name: [''] --> This is an array of string so to get the value, you need to do **mContacts[0].name[0]** --> You'll get the first item of the array and log his name but I dont understand why you have an array here...

You could use lodash to do some stuff [Lodash](https://lodash.com/)

Hope I could help

Comment: Thanks Man, the code works well, 
I kept it simple with just
 pickContact(contactId) {  
    this.contacts.pickContact().then((contact) => {
    this.mContacts[contactId].name = contact.name.givenName;
    this.mContacts[contactId].number = contact.phoneNumbers[0].value;
    });

works well enough for me